# Firefox Mac Javascript problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, firefox

I am having a problem with my JavaScript where it runs into problems on the Mac version of Firefox only. The only console errors are

TypeError: $.tweets.tweet is not a function

TypeError: $.smartbanner is not a function

Using these plugins:

http://forsmo.me/jquery.tweet.js/

https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner

However, when I try to access other Javascript functions that are defined in other scripts through the console, they are almost all undefined.

If I copy and paste the source code from the functions or plugins into the console, then try recalling them, the code can be executed without problem.

Has anybody got any tips on how I can identify the source of the problem? It seems to me like there is probably one or two errors in the JavaScript that are then trickling down and breaking everything else, but I see no way of identifying where those problems are happening.

There are no errors on Firefox for Windows, or any other browsers that I am aware.
The Mac is running OSX 10.9.5 and Firefox 38.0.1.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**! UPDATE:**

I am including the code in the page with this big script element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript_combine/?file%5B%5D=ls_core_jquery&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fjquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fjquery.easing-1.3.min.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fbootstrap.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fjquery.isotope.min.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fjquery.tdautocomplete.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fjquery.sharrre-1.3.4.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fjquery.tweet.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fimagesloaded.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Finfinite_scroll.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fmega_menu.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fjquery.thumbnailslider.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Floadproductimage.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fhighlight_selected_colour.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fjquery.smartbanner.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fsizechartswitch.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fhelperwindow.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Ffield_validate.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fmodules%2Fflynsarmyslideshow%2Fresources%2Fnivo-slider3.2%2Fjquery.nivo.slider.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fla_boutique.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcolour_squares.js&amp;file%5B%5D=%2Fthemes%2Frapanui%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fjquery.elevatezoom.js&ver=1.33"></script>
```

Which is a merged version of all of our javascript files (to reduce the number of files loaded in the page). The two plugin files are included in this file.

The scripts are then called via inline script elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { $.smartbanner() } )
</script>

<script src="/themes/main/resources/js/loadtwitter.js" async=""></script>
```

the contents of the loadtwitter.js file:

```
(function() {
    $tweets = $('#tweets');

    $tweets.tweet({
        username: $tweets.data('username'),
        favorites: false,
        retweets: false, 
        count: 3,
        avatar_size: 60,
        template: '<div class="tweet"><div class="avatar">{avatar}</div><div class="text">{text}{time}</div></div>'
    });
})();
```

Interestingly, when I look in the 'debugger' window in Firefox's inspector, the large file with all of our JS in does not appear in the list of resources, even though it does appear in the pages HTML.

Does this mean that the file is not being loaded in for some reason, despite being in the page itself?

In Firefox for Windows, the js file appears in the list of sources.

Comment: can you show the code where you are including the plugins and how you are calling them, or better yet recreate the issue in a jsfiddle.

Comment: @atmd I have added more information now, could you please take a look and see what you think?

Comment: I think the problem might be in that huge string you have as a source of your script. For example, if you use a backslash instead of a forward slash in your paths, it will work on windows but not on mac.

Comment: The slash direction will only matter if you're running in as a file in the browser. are you using a server?